# Bootstrap responsive on 21 inches screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a small project using Bootstrap. Now I come across a responsive problem, wish someone can help me out.

First and most important problem is: when this web page shown on a 21 inches screen, the layout is totally broken. I tried to adjust the 'lg-col=x', but it still doesn't work.

Similarly, when I show it on a narrow screen, the button doesn't laid nicely.

```js
<!-- Down payment calculation -->

    
function downpayment()     {
  var pvalue = document.formval.p_value.value;
  var down = Math.ceil(pvalue * 0.6);
  document.formval2.field1.value = ("The down payment is " + "$" + down.toFixed(0));    
} 

<!-- Monthly payment calculation -->

    
function monthly()     {        
  var pvalue = document.formval.p_value.value; // pick the form input value (property value)
          
  var rate = document.formval.int_rate.value; // pick the form input value (interest rate)
          
  var t = document.formval.period.value; // pick the form input value (tenure)
  var loan = pvalue * 0.4;        
  var r = rate / 100 / 12; // to calculate monthly rate 
          
  var monthly = (loan * r * Math.pow((1 + r), t * 12)) / (Math.pow((1 + r), t * 12) - 1);
  if (monthly.toFixed(0) == "Infinity") {
    document.formval3.field2.value = ("Please complete the input");
  } else if (monthly.toFixed(0) == "NaN") {
    document.formval3.field2.value = ("Please complete the input");
  } else {
    document.formval3.field2.value = ("The monthly payment is: " + "$" + monthly.toFixed(0));
  }    
}  
<!-- Total amount calculation -->

    
function total()     {        
  var pvalue = document.formval.p_value.value; // pick the form input value (property value)
          
  var rate = document.formval.int_rate.value; // pick the form input value (interest rate)
          
  var t = document.formval.period.value; // pick the form input value (tenure)
  var loan = pvalue * 0.4;        
  var r = rate / (12 * 100); // to calculate rate percentage..
          
  var monthly = (loan * r * Math.pow((1 + r), t * 12)) / (Math.pow((1 + r), t * 12) - 1);
  // to calculate compound interest..
          
  var total = monthly * 12 * t + pvalue * 0.6 + 650;
  if (total.toFixed(0) == "NaN") {
    document.formval4.field3.value = ("Please complete the input");
  } else {
    document.formval4.field3.value = ("The total amount is: " + "$" + total.toFixed(0));
  }

      
}



<!-- JQ effect -->
$(function() {
  $("#Calculated").click(function() {
    $("[name='field1']").show(1000)
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#monthly-Calculate").click(function() {
    $("[name='field2']").show(1000)
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#sum").click(function() {
    $("[name='field3']").show(1000)
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Reset").click(function() {
    $("[name='field3']").slideUp(1000)
    $("[name='field2']").slideUp(1000)
    $("[name='field1']").slideUp(1000)
  })
})
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  background: #000 url("https://s14.postimg.org/brfoy05nl/homeloan.jpg") center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px white;
}

form {
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473181488821-2d23949a045a?dpr=1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=767&amp;h=511&amp;q=80&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;crop=);
  background-size: cover;
}

label {
  display: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
}

.input-group {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #413ba0;
  border-color: black;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #775858;
}

.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #83a03b;
  border-color: black;
}

.btn-success:hover,
.btn-success:focus,
.btn-success:active,
.btn-success.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #775858;
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #a03b97;
  border-color: black;
}

.btn-info:hover,
.btn-info:focus,
.btn-info:active,
.btn-info.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #775858;
}

.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d63e3e;
  border-color: black;
}

.btn-warning:hover,
.btn-warning:focus,
.btn-warning:active,
.btn-warning.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Anmei International</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/g_collection_png/standard/512x512/currency_dollar.png" />
  <link href="http://pg.gaarsam.com//html/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400i|PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Montserrat Light', sans-serif;">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2 style="color:White; font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 60px;">Property Investment Calculator</h2>
  </div>

  <!-- Input form -->
  <form name="formval" class="form-horizontal" style="font-size:20px; color: black; font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; width: 50%; margin-left: 25%">

    <!-- Property Value -->
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 0.5%">
      <label for="input" class="control-label" style="font-weight: bold">Property Value</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="property_value" name="p_value" placeholder="Please input property price" style="font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Loan Tenure -->
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 0.5%">
      <label for="input" class="control-label" style="font-weight: bold">Loan Tenure</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <!-- 15 years -->
        <label style="color: #962121; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 5%;">15 years
      <input type="radio" id="fifteen_years" name="period" value="15" style="font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 3%;" onclick="getValue(this)" required="">
         </label>

        <!-- 30 years -->
        <label style="color: #962121; font-weight: bold;">30 years
      <input type="radio" id="thirty_years" name="period" value="30" style="font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 3%;" onclick="getValue(this)">
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- APR -->
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 0.5%">
      <label for="input" class="control-label" style="font-weight: bold">Annual Percentage Rate</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="idROI" name="int_rate" style="font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">
        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- button -->
    <div class="form-group">

      <!-- Downpayment -->
      <button type="button" id="Calculated" name="calculate" value="downpayment" onclick="downpayment()" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-3 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="margin-right: 2%; padding: 5px;">Calculate down payment</button>

      <!-- Monthly payment -->
      <button type="button" id="monthly-Calculate" name="calculate" value="monthly" onclick="monthly()" class="btn btn-success col-lg-3 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="margin-right: 2%; padding: 5px;">Calculate monthly payment</button>

      <!-- Total -->
      <button type="button" id="sum" name="calculate" value="toal" onclick="total()" class="btn btn-info col-lg-3 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="margin-right: 12%; padding: 5px;">Calculate total amount</button>

      <!-- Reset -->
      <button type="reset" id="Reset" class="btn btn-warning col-lg-1 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="padding: 5px;">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  < <!-- Output form -->
    <!-- Down payment output -->
    <form name="formval2" class="form-horizontal col-lg-3 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-group">
        <output name="field1" style="display:none; font-size:20px; padding:10px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif; color: black; background-color: white; border-radius: 25px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;"></output>
      </div>
      </form>

    <!-- Monthly payment output -->
    <form name="formval3" class="form-horizontal col-lg-3 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-group">
        <output name="field2" style="display:none; font-size:20px; padding:10px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif; color: black; background-color: white; border-radius: 25px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;"></output>
      </div>
      </form>

    <!-- Total amount output -->
    <form name="formval4" class="form-horizontal col-lg-3 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-group">
        <output name="field3" style="display:none; font-size:20px; padding:10px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif; color: black; background-color: white; border-radius: 25px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;"></output>
      </div>
      </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pg.gaarsam.com//html/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pg.gaarsam.com//html/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pg.gaarsam.com//html/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="english.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "lg-col=x"?
"the layout is totally broken." 
Broken how? it works for me as far as I can see?
"Similarly, when I show it on a narrow screen, the button doesn't laid nicely."

You need to provide a sketch or better description of what you expect to see.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply. "lg-col" is the format for bootstrap layout. It works fine on the screen of the laptop but not the big screen(like 21 inches). Lastly, when you shrink the browser, the button shrink in different size. I hope I can upload picture here but I cant

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, I'm not 100% sure of what you are calling broken.

You can upload an image to imgur, then embed the link in your post.

As for your button issue I'm not sure what you are referring to, but one thing to try is to wrap your col classes in a parent .row div